# What do the sections in the mdoc manpage refer to?

Tags: freebsd, man

So I've been looking into writing manpages for a project, and eventually came to the [mdoc man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mdoc&sektion=7). In it, it describes the common layout for manpages as including:

```
   .\" .Sh CONTEXT
   .\" For section 9 functions only.
   .\" .Sh IMPLEMENTATION NOTES
   .\" Not used in OpenBSD.
   .\" .Sh RETURN VALUES
   .\" For sections 2, 3, and 9 function return values only.
   .\" .Sh ENVIRONMENT
   .\" For sections 1, 6, 7, and 8 only.
```

However, I couldn't figure out what these sections 1, 6, 7 and 8 only refer to? My best guess is pages of the manual (e.g. page 2 for system calls) but this didn't make much sense, why would return values not be on page 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice how the referenced man page actually is [mdoc(7)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mdoc&sektion=7). This means it is from section 7 of the man page collection which is *"Miscellaneous"*. If all of the man pages are the full book then think of the sections as chapters.

This then means that you should document `RETURN VALUES` if you want to write a man pages you want to place in section 2, 3 or 9.

Typical commands would be found in section 1 such as [ls(1)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ls&sektion=1) and [du(1)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=du&sektion=1) (both comes with the OS). But external projects usually use the samme mapping such as [postgres(1)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=postgres&sektion=1) and [mysql(1)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mysql&sektion=1). The latter is an example of a not so great man page as it does not reference related pages. You then end up looking on the net to find the [pages](https://www.mankier.com/package/mariadb). Do not be that guy!

See [13.2. Sections](https://docs.freebsd.org/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/fdp-primer/manpages-sections.html) for an enumeration of the categories.

The full (and short) [Chapter 13. Manual Pages](https://docs.freebsd.org/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/fdp-primer/manpages.html) will probably give a more highlevel introduction rather than the man page.

Another highlevel page which people often miss is [intro(7)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mdoc&sektion=7). I think of that as the first page of the *man "book"*. Every section has a *intro* page which describes each section:

No.   Category

1. [General Commands](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=intro&sektion=1)
2. [System Calls](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=intro&sektion=2)
3. [Library Functions](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=intro&sektion=3)
4. [Kernel Interfaces](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=intro&sektion=4)
5. [File Formats](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=intro&sektion=5)
6. [Games](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=intro&sektion=6)
7. [Miscellaneous](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=intro&sektion=7)
8. [System Manager](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=intro&sektion=8)
9. [Kernel Developer](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=intro&sektion=9)

Comment: Ah, so is the idea that rather than there being a section 1 in a manual page, a manual page exists in section 1? Like section 1 contains all of the manual pages relating to general commands?

Comment: Yes. That is correct. Manual pages are grouped into "sections".

Comment: Good use of the indicative.  Oftentimes the manual pages were, and sometimes even still are, available as actual books, and these are the contents.  A common convention with such books was mark the page edges differently for each section so that one could see the individual sections with the books closed.